How to create an associative array of associative arrays in D?
I'm using D to crunch some data, it would be nice for me to be able to have an immutable map of maps that hold direction coordinates. I tried to do this via:
enum Direction
{
    NORTH = "north",
    SOUTH = "south"
}

immutable Direction[int][int] COORD_LOOKUP = [
    3: [2: Direction.NORTH], 1: [3: Direction.SOUTH]
];

However ldc fails with the following:
Error: not an associative array initializer

How can I create this associative array?

Seems like a bug, not LDC specific. https://github.com/dlang/dmd/issues/17804
Per that bug report, the parentheses seem to "work", but causes another failure in static AA initialization.

Yeah it seems that using auto and moving this to runtime makes it work. Weird!
